# Prevent WordPress from wrapping <samp> tags with P and BRs

Tags: wordpress, line-breaks

While building a new theme I found that WordPress wraps all `<samp></samp>` tags with `<p></p>`. According to specs, `<samp>` represents (sample) output from a program or computing system. It's not a block-level element, it can be used inline, as well as `<kbd>`, `<var>` or `<code>`.

The problem is WordPress wraps this tag with paragraph. I managed to solve this issue with this code:

```
function righter_filter_ptags($content) {
    $content = preg_replace('/<p>\s*(<a .*>)?\s*(<img .* \/>)\s*(<\/a>)?\s*<\/p>/iU', '\1\2\3', $content);
    $content = preg_replace('/<p>\s*(<iframe .*>*.<\/iframe>)\s*<\/p>/iU', '\1', $content);
    $content = preg_replace('/<p>\s*(<samp .*>*.<\/samp>)\s*<\/p>/iU', '\1', $content);
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'righter_filter_ptags');
```

It actually strips Ps from images and iframes as well. While it gives the expected results - all `<img>`, `<iframe>` and `<samp>` tags now have no wrapping paragraphs, WordPress now adds `<br>` tag before `<samp>`. I'm working in 'Text' mode and writing everything in one line, with no line breaks. Here's the sample code:

```
We have not only <code>code</code> tag, but also <kbd>kbd</kbd> and <samp>samp</samp> tags.
```

and here's sample output in html source code on the website:

```
<p>
We have not only 
<code>code</code>
tag, but also 
<kbd>kbd</kbd>
and
<br>
<samp>samp</samp>
</p>
<p>
tags.
</p>
```

It looks exactly this, with all line-breaks. Everything is fine except this `<br>` tag right before `<samp>` and the content after `<samp>` get wrapped into another paragraph (the word 'tags.'). Any ideas how to remove it? Did a lot of googling, no result.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, **it's a TinyMCE bug**. Had to spend few more hours on this to figure out...

For some reason, TinyMCE defines a `<samp>` tag as a block-level element, which is definitely wrong.

There is a [WordPress Trac ticket [18807]](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18807) for this bug and it's fixed now, seems to be rolled out with WordPress 3.6 update. Patching my WP sources for now and waiting for 3.6 update.